# Cumulative Probability of at least two successes

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

For this problem, 85% of people wear their mask while working. If there are 9 people working, what is the probability that at least 2 people are NOT wearing their mask?

From my understanding, this is finding $P( k \geq 2)$. I know need to use the a value $p=.15$. Based off notes, I should sum all probabilities for $k=2, 3, 4, ..., 9$.

However, I'm led to believe that $P(k \geq 2)$ is the same as $Q(k \leq 1)$.

NOTE: $P$ denotes the total probability where $p=.15$, $Q$ denotes the total probability where $p=.85$

Either way, I'm not getting the desired answer, which should be $=.4005$.

I plugged in my values into [this calculator](https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx), with the values being: Probability of success on a single trial = $.15$, number of trials = $9$, and number of successes $= 2$, and it showed the cumulative probability $P(k \geq 2) = .4005$.

Is my understanding of the question/approach incorrect? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: YOur notation is hard to follow, since you use the same $P()$  regardless of what the underlying success probability is.  Why not add $p$ to the notation for clarity?

Comment: @lulu Thank you for the suggestion, I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Also:  why would you imagine that $P(k≥2,.15)=P(k≤1,.85)$?  The latter is effectively $0$.

Comment: @lulu $P(k \geq 2, .15)$ represents the probability that at least two people *are not* wearing masks. I'm thinking this is also the same as asking for the probability that at most one person *is* wearing a mask

Comment: No...the event "at least two people are not wearing masks" is the same as the event "at most $7$ people *are* wearing masks".  And, indeed, $P(k≥2,.15)=P(k^c≤7,.85)$.  Where, of course, $k$ counts the people who aren't wearing masks and $k^c$ counts those who are.

Comment: @lulu Ahh, I see now. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: What you want is the rule of complementary probability: $\mathsf P(k\geq 2; 0.15)=1-\mathsf P(k\leq 1; 0.15)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp $P(k \leq 1) = P(k=0) + P(k=1)$, correct? If so, I have tried using this rule and did not arrive at the answer.

Comment: $\begin{align}P(k\geq 2)&=1-\mathsf P(k=0)-\mathsf P(k=1)\\[1ex]&= 1~-~~0.85^9~~-~~9\cdot0.15^1\cdot0.85^8\\[1ex]&\approx 0.4005\end{align}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I am now just realizing I wrote down $p^k$ term in the binomial distribution as $p^2$, and for some reason couldn't catch it for the past hour. Thank you so much!